# For each group in a dataframe, drop rows that postdate a row which meets some criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Within rows sharing the same 'name', how do I drop any rows that postdate a row with negative value?

For instance, in the following example, it would like to filter out rows 2 and 3 as they postdate row 1 which has a negative value.

Input:

```
    name        date   value
0    a    2019-01-06      1
1    a    2019-01-07     -1
2    a    2019-01-08      1
3    a    2019-01-09     -1
4    b    2019-01-06      1
5    b    2019-01-07      1
6    b    2019-01-08      1
7    b    2019-01-09      1
```

Desired Output

```
    name        date   value
0    a    2019-01-06      1
1    a    2019-01-07     -1
4    b    2019-01-06      1
5    b    2019-01-07      1
6    b    2019-01-08      1
7    b    2019-01-09      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cumsum` with bool , then we do shift to include the first `-1` row and all row beyond first -1

```
s=df.value.eq(-1).groupby(df['name']).cumsum()
df[s.eq(0)|s.groupby(df.name).shift().eq(0)]
  name       date  value
0    a 2019-01-06      1
1    a 2019-01-07     -1
4    b 2019-01-06      1
5    b 2019-01-07      1
6    b 2019-01-08      1
7    b 2019-01-09      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but if you use `groupby` on `'name'` and just find the first negative values to use as index:

```
result = df.groupby('name').apply(
    lambda x: x.iloc[:np.where(x['value'] < 0)[0][0] + 1]
    if np.where(x['value'] < 0)[0].any() else x
)
```

Output:

```
       name        date  value
name x                        
a    0    a  2019-01-06      1
     1    a  2019-01-07     -1
b    4    b  2019-01-06      1
     5    b  2019-01-07      1
     6    b  2019-01-08      1
     7    b  2019-01-09      1
```

The `if` statement is there in scenario there is no negative number. If you want to remove the multiindex, you can just drop it with `result.index = result.index.droplevel('name')`.